# Exception trying to write a LogFile using FileStream and StreamWriter

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

So basically I write a windows service that scans any given directory for a zip file and then uploads it to an FTP server. I added a tracing method that suppose to write into a txt file and keep a log of everything. The problems comes when I release the service into windows I get a error message in the Event Viewer( I added a LogEvent using EventLog class) that returns

> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file
>   'C:\Windows\system32\traceLog.txt' because it is being used by another
>   process.

The code that does the tracing is the following

```
private void EscribirTrace(string mensaje)
    {
        if (Tracing)
        {
           try
            {
              using (FileStream archivo2 = new FileStream(string.Format("{0}\\traceLog.txt", Environment.CurrentDirectory), FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    mensaje = string.Format("{0} - {1} \r\n", DateTime.Now, mensaje);

                    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(archivo2);
                    writer.WriteLine(mensaje);
                    writer.Flush();
                    writer.Dispose();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogEvent("Error en escribir tracing", ex);
            }
        }

    }
```

Any ideas would be appreciated

**Edit** So after some research I figure that that system32 is not the best place for the file. My intention was to have that log file at the path were the service was installed. After some research I replaced the

```
Enviroment.CurrentDirectory
```

for

```
Path.GetFullPath(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).Replace(
                Path.GetFileName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

Formated into a string.

The rest just worked pretty well.

Thank you for the responses !

Comment: Does your program have permission to write to system32? what happens if you write it to your desktop for example?

Answer (score 0):

Its because your using statement has not released the file yet.  You have it open in the steam so you can't write to it until you close your stream.

If you want to simply write text to a file just use:

```
File.WriteAllText(FILEPATH, TEXTDATA);
```

That call will open the file, write to it, and then close it.

Answer (score 0):

if it throws on the using ...make sure all other streams on the file are closed properly ...

if it throws on the streamwriter constructor

change the using to be the stream writer with the new filestream in the constructor

Answer (score 0):

/Windows/system32 requires admin access. Your application probably isn't running with the proper privileges. You should try writing the log to a different (less restrictive) location. If you need to write to system32 ensure that your service is running with admin privileges.